# Convert input DateTime with javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm building an iPhone app with Cordova and i use the native DateTime picker like this:

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="date" name="date" value="" />
```

When I save the form and push it to my Local database WebDB it saves like this:

```
row.datetime // 2014-04-03T21:23
```

What i would like to do is this:

```
<span>hh:mm</span><br>   
<span>dd-mm-yyyy</span>
```

Is there any way to do this using Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my final solution:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GCHg3/

```
var strDate = "2014-04-03T21:23";
var dateParts = strDate.split(/-|T/);
var datetime = "<span>" + dateParts[3] + "</span><br><span>" + dateParts[2] + "-" + dateParts[1] + "-" + dateParts[0] + "</span>";

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += datetime;
```

Comment: On iPhone sometimes when you save the time, it saves micro seconds too, fixed this in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ED8yY/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JS library to format the date time. Something like MomentJS - http://momentjs.com/ or DateJS - http://www.datejs.com/ would allow you to format. Otherwise, if you don't want that much to deal with, use the built-in JavaScript methods to get the date and time values and build your own strings.

Refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date for detailed information. The Getter methods are important for your case. JS date objects support getMonth, getDate, getFullYear, getHours, getMinutes, etc... and you can grab these values into variables and build your string from them.

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zS77J/

Code:

```
var dt = new Date();    // new date obj

// use date methods to get values
var hr = dt.getHours();
var mn = dt.getMinutes();
var dy = dt.getDate();
var mo = dt.getMonth();
var yr = dt.getFullYear();

var timeStr = hr+':'+mn;    // time string with hours and mins
var dateStr = dy+'-'+mo+'-'+yr;    // date format dd-mm-yyyy
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Chose an alternative anwser, but still thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `datetime` property, but [`valueAsDate`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/common-input-element-apis.html#dom-input-valueasdate). You can easily build your string from that:

```
var row = document.getElementById("date");
var dt = row.valueAsDate;
if (!dt || isNaN(dt))
    return '<span class="error">Invalid Date</span>';
else
    return '<span>'+pad(dt.getUTCHours())+':'+pad(dt.getUTCMinutes())+'</span><br>'
         + '<span>'+pad(dt.getUTCDate())+'-'+pad(dt.getUTCMonth()+1)+'-'+dt.getUTCFullYear()+'</span>';

function pad(v) { return ('0'+v).slice(-2); }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Chose an alternative anwser, but still thanks.